# NullReferenceException on Connection Open

Tags: windows-mobile, nullreferenceexception, sqlconnection

I am having a NullReferenceException while opening my connection in Windows Mobile 6.5.
My code is like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();
```

I have tried this code in C# windows form application and its working but in windows mobile its not

Comment: I do not think you will have SQL server in your windows mobile. your Data Source shows that you are pointing to a local SQL server. SqlConnection can not find local SQL server hence unable to create a connection. Therefore conn is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *have* an instance of SQLEXPRESS running on the mobile device? I suspect not but, even if you do, I don't believe you can use the *name* in the connection string, it's limited to the TCP/IP address and port.

You probably need to change your connection string so that it attempts to use the right location for the SQL server.

By way of example, if your server was running on the `10.5.5.5` machine at port `9999`, you would change:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;...
```

to:

```
Data Source=10.5.5.5,9999;...
```

Comment: do i have to include the \SQLEXPRESS when using IP?

Comment: @jeraldov, no, I don't think you're actually _allowed_ to, based on a cursory web search. Using the name appears to cause exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to download/install SQL Server CE (SQL Server Mobile, SQL Server Compact, the names change every year). Then add reference to the compact framework SQL library.

You can either connect to a local database on the device using SQLCE (http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce) or to a remote SQL Server using System.Data.SQLClient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275613%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Compact Framework SQLClient does not support all connection options available as in full framwework, see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x984482z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

~josef